# Maven: How to install my jar to local repo after building

Tags: java, maven

I want to build a package and install it to my local repo. My pom file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- This block declare a dependencies for this project -->
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <!-- This block declare a plugins -->
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>

<!-- Installing to local repo -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
                    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    <file>/Users/me/MyApp/target/MyApp-1.0.0.jar</file>
                    <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-jar-lib</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But when I run "mvn package" comand I get a error that there is no file: /Users/me/MyApp/target/MyApp-1.0.0.jar So I comment install plugin, run "mvn package", uncoment install plugin and run "mvn package". Could I do this thing in one step? Without this comment-uncomment thing?

Comment: Remove the whole configuration for `maven-install-plugin` and just use `mvn clean install` that's it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear why you need to invoke the `install-file` goal of `maven-install-plugin` but the problem lies in the phase. You configured it with `<phase>validate</phase>` when it should be `<phase>package</phase>` instead.

Take a look at the [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html): phase `validate` is the first phase that is executed by Maven. At this time, the jar was not built so it can't work.

If you really want the artifact to be installed on the package phase (when running `mvn package`) then the phase should be set to `package`.

Note that instead of running `mvn package`, you should just call `mvn install` without the need of configuring the `maven-install-plugin`. The artifact will be automatically installed in your local repo with this command.

Answer (score 0):

from what i know, mvn clean install, put the package in the local repo, without any need of any plugin